# Django POST request not working correctly

Tags: python, ajax, django, post, request

I have a Django Project I am currently working on where I want to be able to add a product to a database. I have a few fields where the user enters the details of the product and this is then sent to the create function and should save it to the Database. Unfortunately this isnt happening. This is my first use of Django so I'm not sure whats going wrong here. Here is the code I have  so far:

My Index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create product here</h2>
<div>
<form id="new_user_form" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div>
  <label for="name" > Name:<br></label>
  <input type="text" id="name"/>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
  <label for="description"> description:<br></label>
  <input type="text" id="description"/>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="price" > price:<br></label>
  <input type="text" id="price"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </div>
</form>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/text/javascript">

  $(document).on('submit', '#new_user_form', function(e)){
    e.preventDefault()

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:'/user/create',
      data:{
        name:$('#name').val(),
        description:$('#description').val(),
        price:$('#price').val(),
      }
      success.function(){
        console.log('created')
      }    
    })
  }    
</script>
</html>
```

Here is my urls.py code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from testapp import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index),
    path('user/create', views.create_product, name='create_user')
]
```

My views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from testapp.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

@csrf_exempt
def create_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        description = request.POST['description']
        price = request.POST['price']

        User.objects.create(
            name = name,
            description = description,
            price = price
        )

        return HttpResponse('')
```

And the models.py code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    desscription = models.TextField()
    price = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
```

The problem with this is the POST request is sent when run, but the data is not saved to the database and I can't figure out why. I have followed a couple tutorials and documentation to get to this stage but can't work out what it is that's not working correctly here. Can someone have a look and let me know please?

Comment: When you print the values of name, description, and price (in the POST routine), do they have data in them?

Comment: You've got a few things going on here, you should try and simplify to eliminate the possibilities. For instance, does it work if you take away the JS and do a simple form submission without Ajax?

Comment: @JonahBishop no, tried adding a console.log function in the JavaScript but nothing is printed to the console.

Comment: @DanielRoseman still sends a post request, but again that data isnt going anywhere

Comment: Well, you don't have an action attribute on the form so you're posting back to the index. What if you do `<form action="/user/create" ...>`?